# best way to unit test spark streaming Using sbt

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I wonder what is the best way to unit test spark streaming flow.

(Using sbt)

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This guide pretty much covers end to end testing of a Spark Streaming application via scalatest: http://mkuthan.github.io/blog/2015/03/01/spark-unit-testing/

This same behavior can be replicated in pyspark with nearly the same code.